# access some elements of JSON string

Tags: jquery, json

This is what I did in code behind:

```
 [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat =  ResponseFormat.Json)]

public static string CheckInsertRecord(String EventType, String BeginDate, String EndDate)
{
    NCDCPoint ncdc = new NCDCPoint();
    CEOSurveyDataContext CDC = new CEOSurveyDataContext();
    int et = Convert.ToInt32(EventType);
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime b = Convert.ToDateTime(BeginDate);
    DateTime e = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);

   var query = (from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
                where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et && n.BeginDate == b && n.EndDate == e
                select new { 
                   n.EVENT_TYPE_ID,
              BeginDate =  n.BeginDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd",provider),
               EndDate = n.EndDate.ToString(),
                n.BeginLAT,
              BeginLONG =  n.BeginLONG,
                n.EndLAT,
                n.EndLONG});


   if (query.Any())
   {
       return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(query.ToList());
   }
   else
   {
       return "No duplicate";
   }



}
```

So I Send this string back to jquery. I;m trying to access only the EVENT_TYPE_ID value. 
So, i tried using alert(msg.d[0]);

But to my dissapointment I only get "[" this as theresult. SO, can u please help me how to access only EVENT_TYPE_ID value?

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "Data.aspx/CheckInsertRecord",
            data: "{EventType:'" + eventtype + "',BeginDate:'" + begindate + "'," +
                   "EndDate:'" + enddate+"' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

       //var prof = eval("(" + msg.d+ ")")
           var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);

        alert(msg.d[0]);
           alert("A record of this event already exists in the database.\n" + msg.d+".");


            }
        });
```

This is the JSON string

```
{
  "EVENT_TYPE_ID": 1,
  "BeginDate": "2011-06-03",
  "EndDate": "2011-06-11",
  "BeginLAT": null,
  "BeginLONG": null,
  "EndLAT": null,
  "EndLONG": null
}
```

Comment: Can you show the rendered JSON?

Comment: That's the Javascript. What is the JSON sent from the server?

Comment: serialise (query.Tolist()) is the JSON string that is sent. Serialize coverts an object to JSON string

Comment: Yes, I know. What is the actual JSON data sent in the HTTP request from the server to the browser? You should be able to see this with the browser console.

Comment: Well something definitely does not compute: the C# code is serializing a List<T>, so I would have expected an array to be encoded in the JSON stream, yet the JSON quoted just shows a single object. The demons of the interwebs strike again.

Answer (score 0):

This should work I think,

```
$.getJSON('Data.aspx/CheckInsertRecord', {EventType:eventtype,BeginDate:begindate,EndDate:enddate}, function(data){
 alert(data["EVENT_TYPE_ID"]);
});
```

or

```
alert(msg.d["EVENT_TYPE_ID"]);
```

Comment: still the alert gives me Undefined. K. let me update the entire code for you

Comment: I updated the post, but I don't thik thats gonna make much difference

Comment: @nishanth change $.parseJSON(msg.d) to $.parseJSON(msg), or debug the js and see what the value of msg.d is.

Comment: @Andrew: msg.d is the JSON scipt I wrote in the post.

Comment: when i use $.parseJSON(msg), the code is not getting executed.

Comment: @nishanth Try using the call that I suggest in the first half of my post. Otherwise I con't help you because your question doesn't match your actual code...

Comment: Can u just let me know whether the way I did makes it to difficult to retrieve the first attribute of the query

Answer (score 0):

The reason that isn't working is that you're assigning `$.parseJSON()`'s result to `data`, but then trying to access the object via `msg.d`, which is still just a JSON string.  Strings may also be accessed as arrays of characters in JavaScript, so `msg.d[0]` is literally referencing the first character of your JSON, which is the opening array bracket.

If you used `data[0]` instead, you'd get what you're after. However, **I'd like to strongly advise against continuing down that path**.

What you may not realize is that [ASP.NET automatically handles JSON serialization for you](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/) in this case.  The JSON string that you've manually built there is then being automatically JSON serialized a second time.  On the client-side, jQuery is receiving the JSON string ASP.NET produced with your return value, parsing it, and then handing you the inner JSON string, which you're then parsing a second time.  That duplication of effort is needlessly inefficient on both client and server.

Do this on the server-side instead:

```
public static IEnumerable CheckInsertRecord(String EventType, String BeginDate, String EndDate)
{


  var query = // Your LINQ query here

  // You can simplify this by just returning the result. If it's empty,
  //  it's easy to test for that on the client-side - easier than watching
  //  for the magic string.
  return query;
}
```

Then, you'll have access to it on the client-side immediately after jQuery finishes its automatic deserialization:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: "Data.aspx/CheckInsertRecord",
  data: "{EventType:'" + eventtype + "',BeginDate:'" + begindate + "'," +
        "EndDate:'" + enddate+"' }",
  success: function (msg) {
    if (msg.d.length === 0)
      alert("No duplicate");
    else
      alert(msg.d.length + " duplicate events already exist!");
  }
});
```

Nice and easy.

If you're curious about why I changed the $.ajax() parameters, see this post for some [information on how you can eliminate some extraneous verbosity from jQuery calls to ASP.NET services](http://encosia.com/save-yourself-some-typing-when-you-call-asp-net-services/).

Answer (score -1):

Retrieving and going through JSON objects:

```
$.getJSON(
  url,
  { p1:p1,
    p2:p2 
  },
  function(data){
     $.each(data, function(key, val) {
         alert("key:"+key+";val:"+val+"-"); 
     });
  }
};
```